# $.ajax unexpected token error on tomcat server (GWT)

Tags: jquery, ajax, gwt, tomcat

we are currently working on a GWT Project and ran into an unexpected token error called by .parseJSON in this function after compiling and running the project on a tomcat server. In dev mode on eclipse this worked fine:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "index/sequences/seq.json",
  datatype: "json",
  }).success(function(data) {
var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
  });
```

This is the json; validated by jsonlint

```
{"cont":[{"values":"left arm up,turn left,sit","name":"greet&go"},{"values":"turn left,turn right,walk back","name":"strange moves"},{"values":"kick right,turn right, right arm up","name":"right moves"},{"values":"kick right,walk,sit","name":"sequnece 4"},{"values":"sit,stand,kick left","name":"up&down"},{"values":"stand,turn right,sit","name":"testin"},{"values":"turn left,kick right","name":"kickit!"},{"values":"turn right,look up,left arm out,walk","name":"greet the audience"}]}
```

After some debugging i realized, that the parseJSON is called two times; first time with no errors, right data and all, second time with empty data, what calls the error.

Any help welcome!
THX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datatype` should be `dataType`, and if you are supplying the `dataType` parameter (or passing the appropriate `Content-Type: application/json header`), you don't need to parse the json.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "index/sequences/seq.json",
  dataType: "json"
}).success(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```